# How could a PHP method call itself by magic methods?

Tags: php

I have this:

```
function callMe()
{
    // return $this->callMe();
    return $this->__FUNCTION__();
}
```

This one doesn't work:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Classss::__FUNCTION__()
```

But what if I don't want to duplicate the name of the method?

Comment: Why do you need to use magic methods?

Comment: See [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func).

Comment: AFAIK `__FUNCTION__` returns the name of the function. So it cannot be converted to a function call by just adding `()` s.

Comment: @MarkBaker: "But what if I dont want to duplicate the name of the method?"

Comment: Aside from (possibly) saving a few keystrokes, I don't really see any need to be able to do this (although you can), especially as it reduces the readability of the method.... and in your case above will result in a stack overflow

Comment: doesn't this sort of create an infinite loop?  Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, But I recommend not doing it.

```
class Test {
    public function f() {
        echo "called";
        $fn_name = __FUNCTION__;
        $this->$fn_name();
        // Equally valid:
        // $this->{__FUNCTION__}();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function callMe(  ){
   return call_user_func(
      array( $this, __METHOD__ )
      //(optional) , $argument1, $argument2, ....
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An apporach like [**this**](http://3v4l.org/7Ni7H) will work too.

```
<?php

callMe(0);

function callMe($count)
{
    $count++;
    echo $count . " ";
    if($count > 10){
        return;
    }
    call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $count);
}
?>
```